# Why I am getting windows security alert in IE but not Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am getting this security alert popup when using IE but not chrome. Did anyone experience this issue and were you able to resolve it?

Comment: What security alert?

Comment: When you ask completely indecipherable, incomplete questions like this you're going to risk an automatic question ban.

Answer (score 0):

the security pop up is related to the Load Balancer timing out. In Chrome, the popup is not showing but at the background it is throwing an error. So the fix is to increase the Load Balancer so that the tcp connection stays alive until it times out at the backend.